# SSMS: connect to SQL Server through 2 RDP connections

Tags: sql-server, connection-string

A difficult construction, I think.

I need to connect to a SQL Server through my local SSMS.

At the moment I only can connect to database when I open RDP connection to a virtual machine and use another RDP on that VM to connect to windows 2012 server where a SSMS gives me access to the desired database.

Now, I have to make a lot of updates on that database with adding data which is stored in my local database outside this network!

I can't make it and do not find any information to create a connection.

For example:
In the RDP the computername is: 
  webmail.myserver.com:15901 
my username is: 
  theDomain\my.name

then I reach the VM on the Windows 2012 server.

There is another RDP which I use with this computername:
 srv-ourserver\theDomain
my username is:
 my.name

Then I am on the Windows 2012 server and can connect through SSMS to the SQL-Server called 
 srv-ourserver\SQLExpress

There is firewall rule on the Windows 2012 server on port 15999 (not 15901!) and on the SQL-Server the TCP/IP protocol has a TCP-Port 15999 but also a dynamic port setting.

I do not know if I can delete the dynamic port setting to make connection for the other users within the company, but they all use a DSN with a servername "srv-ourserver\SQLExpress, 15999", so I think I could delete the dynamic port setting?

But again, the question is, if and how I can connect from outside (over internet) from my local notebook to the server database.

Thanks for a guide through!

Michael

Comment: This sounds like the issue is less to do with SQL Server, but more a networking issu, if you have to RDP to the host machine, and the RDP from that to the VM, rather than RDPing straight to the SQL Server Virtual Host. You haven't actually asked a question in your **question** though, so you might want to do that too. :)

Comment: Well, I thought that I asked correctly HOW to reach the database under this construction which is indeed somehow strange but out of my responsibility, I just can take it like it is.